# Am I allowed to use custom scripts on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have a script that downloads images from Facebook Messenger automatically. I need it for work, and I was wondering, does this break Facebook policy or something? Could I get my account banned?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by script? Is this JavaScript which runs in the browser or an external script (such as Python) which is fetching the images remotely? Either way, it's almost certainly against Facebook policy. However, Facebook has many APIs which facilitate data collection.

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut It's JavaScript that gets injected with tampermonkey, it's pretty simple, click download -> go to next photo -> repeat

Answer (score 1):

The rules regarding the use of automated scripts with Facebook's services is outlined [here](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php).

> Quote: "2. You will not engage in Automated Data Collection without Facebook's express written permission."

Comment: "You will not engage in Automated Data Collection without Facebook's express written permission" is there a way to get permission ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Your comment on your question suggests that this isn't an automated process. "go to next photo -> repeat". If this is merely a client-side downloader which simplifies the process of downloading an image already present on the screen, that should be fine.